# integrating magnolia and spring mvc,hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, magnolia

We are integrating spring MVC into Magnolia using blossom plugin.

Below are the steps we followed to intergate.

-Created blossom project and then added some service classed and templates.

- Done a build which will generate an Jar file
- Copied the Jar file to the MagnoliaAuthur/lib folder
- copied all dependency jar files(Hibernate jar files)
- Start the tomcat

Is this the correct way to integrate Magnolia and Spring MVC ?
Is there any different ways we can set up the integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good start. What you need to do next is annotate your controllers, add there extra methods (and annotations) for building dialogs and exposing what you want to be editable via Magnolia to the users and modify views to actually consume and display what was added by editors.

I suggest you follow [the documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module). There's quite few good examples there and lot of details you should find useful.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks Jan,just want to confirm is that the correct approach for creating spring mvc with magnolia...all the spring mvc intgeration has to be run on the magnoliaauthor ..we just need to build and copy the project jar into magnolia author?

Comment: Alos Jan, rather than generating an Jar..is there anyway I can use like an webapp..so that it is easy to debug the code in run time.

Comment: You need to have module installed on every instance where you want that integration running. During development, you would typically use just one instance (author) but for production, you need both.    
Whether or not you can use exploded archive instead of war file depends on the app server you are using. No problem if you are using Tomcat for example.